# ImageView is blank after setting Uri (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, uri, crop

So am actually implementing a feature where user selects image from gallery and then in this activity if the user clicks on crop button a layout from this library becomes visible https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper then the user can crop and then click another button to save it.
But the problem is after cropping the image when clicked on cropclose it the layout goes away and imageview shows the cropped image but it just shows a blank image.

Edit- I found the problem thanks to @Usama Altaf

So I added a Log logging the image uri and it said this
24333-24333/com.margsapp.messenger D/imageUri: null
So the problem is imageuri is null How to fix this?

```
public class SendImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CropImageView.OnSetImageUriCompleteListener,
    CropImageView.OnCropImageCompleteListener {

ImageView imageView;

ImageView cancel, cropopen,cropclose, edit_open,edit_close;

EditText text;

ImageButton btn_send;

CropImageView cropImageView;

PhotoEditorView photoEditorView;

Uri imageUri;

Intent intent;

RelativeLayout messagebox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_image);

    intent = getIntent();

    imageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("imageUri"));


    btn_send = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
   
    cropopen = findViewById(R.id.cropopen);
    cropclose = findViewById(R.id.cropclose);
    cropImageView = findViewById(R.id.cropImageView);
   
    cropopen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            

            cropImageView.setImageUriAsync(imageUri);

            cropImage();


        }
    });

    cropclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cropImage();
            cropImageView.getCroppedImageAsync();






        }
    });



   

    

    


}

private void cropImage() {

    cropImageView.setOnSetImageUriCompleteListener(this);
    cropImageView.setOnCropImageCompleteListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onSetImageUriComplete(CropImageView view, Uri uri, Exception error) {
    if (error == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image load successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Log.e("AIC", "Failed to load image by URI", error);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image load failed: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCropImageComplete(CropImageView view, CropImageView.CropResult result) {
    handleCropResult(result);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        handleCropResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleCropResult(CropImageView.CropResult result) {
    if(result.getError() == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image crop Success: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        imageUri = result.getUri();

        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        

        cropImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       
        
    }

    else {
        Log.e("AIC", "Failed to crop image", result.getError());
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Image crop failed: " + result.getError().getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: check if your imageUri is actually giving a uri or not?

Comment: How to check that exactly? Using toast print the image uri in string?

Comment: check with `Log.d();`

Comment: The whole app is crashing for some unrelated reason when I tried to add Log.d(); as well as Toast

Comment: add `Log.d("imageUri",imageUri );`

Comment: I have wrapped the imageUri inside String.valuof and in log it says this 24333-24333/com.margsapp.messenger D/imageUri: null Now I can clearly see the problem but I dont have idea on how to fix this

Comment: in which method you are getting problem or getting null?

Comment: In the end in private void handleCropResult where am setting the uri in image view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234162/discussion-between-margs-global-and-usama-altaf).